# Have the userform textbox link to the same row as the combobox value but a different column

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform with comboboxes and a textbox. I would like the textbox to link to the cell 2 columns over from the value of combobox1. How would I go about doing so?

Also if the combobox/textbox is blank I would like the linked cells value to remain as is.

The code below for populating the userform comboboxes.

```
 With Worksheets("ML")
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ComboBox1.Value
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ComboBox2.Value
.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).AutoFill 
.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).Resize(2)

With .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).Resize(2)
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With
With Worksheets("CT")
  .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ComboBox2.Value
  .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 21).AutoFill 
  .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 21).Resize(2)
With .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).Resize(2)
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With


ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Unload Me
End Sub
```

I would like the value of the Combobox1 to display at the next available cell in column A then I would like the textbox1 to show up in the same row as the combobox value but in column AE. In the same row as both the textbox value and the combobox value I would like the columns up to AM to be filled down. Finally I would like the columns up to AM have borders.
[image: Worksheet Monthly FGL Report]

Comment: You could reuse the same code `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ComboBox1.Value`, just add 2 to the column `offset`, i.e.: `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2) = TextBox.Value`. As for keeping values if blank, you should wrap each of your value allocations within an if statement, something like `if combobox1.value <> "" then...`

Comment: Please clarify:  Do you want the value from the "cell 2 columns over from the value of combobox1" to be placed in the `TextBox` or vice versa

Comment: Cell 2 columns over from the linked cell of the combobox @GMalc

Comment: @DarXyde           This is what I tried so far but I can nothing is displaying if I input into the textbox. I also don't think anything is happening when it is left blank.     With Worksheets("ML")
        If TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2) = TextBox1.Value
        .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 43).AutoFill .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 43).Resize(2)
        Else
        End If
        End With
 ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
 Unload Me

Comment: @Tmacjoshua not sure if this comes with a question?

Comment: That is the code I tried which is doing nothing. Would you mind helping me with the if then statement? @DarXyde

Comment: Please see the response as answer... indentation is horrible (well, lack of) in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming here that filldown is what you want instead of autofill (get the formulas from last row). See if this works for you.

```
Dim shtML As Worksheet: Set shtML = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ML") 'Set this to the correct workbook
Dim rngDest As Range
Dim lRow As Long

If ComboBox1.Value <> "" And TextBox1.Value <> "" Then  'Use <[ Or ]> instead of <[ And ]> as you see fit
    With shtML
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1 'Get the first free row
        Set rngDest = .Range(.Cells(lRow, 1), .Cells(lRow, 39))

        With rngDest
            .FillDown 'In the same row as both the textbox value and the combobox value I would like the columns up to AM to be filled down
            .Cells(1, 1) = ComboBox1.Value   'the value of the Combobox1 to display at the next available cell in column A
            .Cells(1, 31) = TextBox1.Value   'the textbox1 to show up in the same row as the combobox value but in column AE
            .Resize(1, .Columns.Count + 5).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous  'Finally I would like the columns up to AM have borders (+5 past the fill down range).
        End With
    End With
End If
```

**EDIT:** made changes as per last discussion...

Comment: It links the textbox to the correct cell but line .Offset(-1, 1).Resize(0, 43).AutoFill causes the Run-time error '1--4': Appliation-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: If TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
    With Worksheets("Monthly FGL Report")
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 30) = TextBox1.Value
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 43).AutoFill .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 43).Resize(2)
            With .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 43).Resize(2)
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous                                                           This does not display an error but does not do anything past pasting the textbox1 value

Comment: See the updated answer... i haven't tested before. The error you've mentioned is because: 1. resize requires at least 1 row, 0 is not a good value (my bad for filling a 0 here). 2. Autofill requires at least 1 range parameter `sourcerange.autofill destinationrange`

Comment: I`m not quite sure on the right ranges you need, but if you try to describe (or show with a picture) how you want the end result to be, I can make the above much better.

Comment: Pciture added, I appreciate the help!

Comment: That's a bit more clear now.. how about `In the same row as both the textbox value and the combobox value I would like the columns up to AM to be filled down.` filled down with what values? and down to last row starting from first row? or take formulas from above them? or... ?

Comment: See the updated answer, let me know if i can help further.

Comment: Thank you. How would I extend the bordering past the filldown. In this case it would be another 5 columnn to the right

Comment: `.Resize(1, .Columns.Count + 5).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous` I'll update the answer too.

Comment: Something like `if range.value = combobox.value then range.offset(0,31).value = combobox.value else range.value = combobox.value end if` (31 columns to the right)